# How to change the message "The Report is empty"

Tags: jasper-reports

I use JasperSoft 6.0.3. If the sql query results no data then the report shows a message saying **"The report is empty"**. I want to **change that message to** "First go to the Report1". How can I do that?

I know about the "*WhenNoDataType*" property. I want to set it as "*No Pages*" or "*NULL*" and change the message.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `whenNoDataType` (When No Data property in iReport) report's attribute for showing "empty" report --> `whenNoDataType="NoDataSection"`

The generated document will contain only a single noData section (band)

In case using noData section you should add this band to the report's template

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just found these two articles also.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/blog/tip-display-no-data-found-message-jasper-ireport

http://jasperguide.blogspot.com/2014/08/enable-no-data-band.html

Comment: nice! good for you... if you think the answer is correct, please accept it in order to give the thread more visibilty/completeness